# How to use setImageTintList() on Android API < 21

Tags: android, android-support-library

```
imgView.setImageTintList(getResources()
      .getColorStateList(R.color.my_clr_selector));
```

It says 'Call requires API level 21'.

How can I make it work on Android devices below API 21?

I can make it work by using `ImageView#setColorFilter()` but I prefer to use a `ColorStateList` to set tint.

Comment: use `DrawableCompat#setTintList()`

Comment: @pskink but getResources().getColorStateList is deprecated

Comment: and you dont know what to use instead?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should use [`ImageViewCompat#setImageTintList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ImageViewCompat.html#setImageTintList(android.widget.ImageView,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)) to achieve this. On API 21+, it will use `ImageView#setImageTintList()` as you would expect... and on older platform versions, it will delegate to `AppCompatImageView` which provides a backported implementation.

```
ColorStateList csl = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_color_state_list);
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, csl);
```

Comment: Just a note that `AppCompatResources` was only added in 24.x of the support library (I think). You could potentially use `ResourcesCompat` which was introduced a few versions earlier.

Comment: I'd use `AppCompatResources` instead wherever possible, since it is able to resolve theme attributes declared inside `ColorStateList` XML even on pre-Marshamallow devices (read more about that in [my blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/contextcompat-getcolor-getdrawable.html)).

Comment: Nice but so lame since API 21 has a single line code to achieve the same but API < 21 still struggle; no support in `DrawableCompat` or `ViewCompat`.

Comment: It works for me. My support library version is 24.3.1.

Comment: The first parameter of the setTintList() method takes in a Drawable object which the documents state "The Drawable against which to invoke the method". Therefore you do not need to call imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable); Already has been applied to the imageView. The following code should do the exact same; only lesser lines of code:

ColorStateList csl = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.my_clr_selector);
DrawableCompat.setTintList(imageView.getDrawable(), csl);

Comment: Updated my answer... you can use `ImageViewCompat#setImageTintList()` now!

Answer (score 5):

This is now available in Support Library 25.4.0. See [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ImageViewCompat.html)

ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, colorStateList)

Comment: `ImageViewCompat` is not available in the latest version of SDK anymore. I am not even sure if it was there, though mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @sud007 must use like this : `ColorStateList csl = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(act, R.color.colorPrimary);
            ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList( ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ic_edt)), csl);`

Comment: @ArMo372 Yeah I am aware of how I would use that but I then I was unable to find any such class in the code. Will see next time and comment if   possible. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 4):

```
int colorInt = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryColor);
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(ivImage, ColorStateList.valueOf(colorInt));
```