# Change icon color of FAB based on state w/ compat libs

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, floating-action-button

I am trying to change the icon color of the icon within a FAB based on the button state:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:tint="@color/add_button_tint"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```

add_button_tint.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <item android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

This works great in API > 23, however in older versions of android, it throws an exception.

Here is where I get confused:

the android:tint property lives within the support FAB and works if its just a color, even in older versions of android.  IE this works in all versions I tested:

```
android:tint="@color/black
```

But when I use the selector it does not.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it possible to change the icon color based on state for a FAB in older versions of android?

Comment: have you tried doing this in code via FloatingActionButton's setImageTintList()?

Comment: setImageTintList() is only available on api 21 and greater.  I Need an appcompat way to tint that icons color.

Comment: I feel like this is a bug or oversight in that FAB does not extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView, instead it extends the non appcompat version.  Which seems bad as FAB is in the widget support lib.

Comment: @Iostintranslation Post the code for map:backgroundTint="@color/add_button_background". Also the namesapce used for map.

Comment: @Anurag that is the normal app namespace, just a different name. Don't care about backgroundTint, it works just fine. Took it out of the question. Same problem still exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ColorStateList in android:tint was not supported prior to API 21.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204671

---

You can use AppCompat's `AppCompatResources` and support-v4 `DrawableCompat` to support pre-lollipop. First, remove `android:tint="@color/add_button_tint"` from your layout. Then set the `ColorStateList` programmatically:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
ColorStateList csl = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, R.color.add_button_tint);
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(fab.getDrawable());
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, csl);
fab.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

See [How to use setImageTintList() on Android API < 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437254/how-to-use-setimagetintlist-on-android-api-21)